# Extracting block of comments from a file

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to extract all the block comments from a file and display them in an array:

my example text looks like this:

```
 /*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */

[SOME OTHER CONTENT IS HERE]

/*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */

[SOME OTHER CONTENT IS HERE]

//*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */

[SOME OTHER CONTENT IS HERE]
```

I tried to do a preg_match_all, to get all the content between /* and */ but it just returns empty. This is my code:

```
preg_match_all("'\^\s*/*!(.*?)*\/'si", $source, $m);
list(,$data['description']) = $m;
```

this is the first time I am attempting to do regular expressions, so I apologise if the solution is straight forward, I have looked at many tutorials but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. TIA!

Comment: Why not use PHP's built-in tokenizer to do this rather than regexp?

Comment: @MarkBaker I am not sure what you mean by tokenizer. Could you maybe post an example?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to escape the * before the ! and at the end, also should not escape the ^

```
preg_match_all("'^\s*/\*!(.*)\*\/'si", $source, $m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
preg_match_all("/\/\*[\s\S]+?\*\//", $source, $m);
```

I used `[\s\S]+` to match the line breaks.

### Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */
            [1] => /*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */
            [2] => /*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have a couple of solutions here, but I thought I'd chime in my 2 cents anyway.  You can try this:

```
preg_match_all('~(/\*!.*?\*/)~s', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */
    [1] => /*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */
    [2] => /*! @brief some example text
 *
 * @param some example text
 * @return some example text
 * @todo documentation to be done.
 */
)
```

Explanation of REGEX:

```
(   /\*!   .*?   \*/   )
      ^     ^     ^
      1     2     3
```

1. Look for a forward slash, followed by an escaped (literal) asterisk, followed by an exclamation mark.
2. Grab anything that it finds all the way up to the asterisk forward slash combination.
3. Look for a literal asterisk followed by a forward slash.